# UnicodeDecodeError pythontex

Tags: pythontex, ascii

An error occurred when I try to compile the following minimal example with xelatex --8bit and pythontex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{pythontex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{Première section}

\py{1+10}

\end{document}
```

After a pythontex execution, I obtain the following message.

```
This is PythonTeX 0.16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/TeX/texbin/pythontex", line 62, in <module>
    pythontex.main()
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex2.py", line 2712, in main
    parse_code_write_scripts(data, temp_data, engine_dict)
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex2.py", line 1099, in parse_code_write_scripts
    interactive)
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex_engines.py", line 456, in get_script
    workingdir_full = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), workingdir).replace('\\', '/')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 73, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix it ? For typesettings, I use TeXPad on MacOS with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Texpad build (.tpbuild) file to use PythonTeX within Texpad
# NB this is to demonstrate pythontex only, it would need alterations     to support bibliographies, indices, etc.

xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE"
pythontex --runall=true "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT"
bibtex "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT"
xelatex -8bit "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE"
xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE"
```

or simply

```
xelatex -8bit namefile
pythontex --runall=true namefile
bibtex namefile
xelatex -8bit namefile
xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 namefile
```

on a shell.

Comment: Do you by any chance have non-ASCII characters in the path of your working directory? `pythontex3` (based on Python 3) doesn't have problems with that.

Comment: Thank's Sergei for your suggestion. If I use pythontex --interpreter python:python3 I get the same error.

Comment: I put my files on my desktop and all work fine. I'd hope to find a solution for general paths containing non-ASCII characters.

Comment: `pythontex --interpreter python:python3` still uses Python 2 at the first stage to execute python3 then. Don't you have the pythontex3 script which would load pythontex3.py from the start?

Comment: How can I run `pythontex` using `pythontex3.py` specifically ? I found the file `pythontex3.py` in the finder.

Comment: Something like `python3 /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py yourfilename`

Comment: Thank's again Sergei. I get the following error message about `pygments` : `line 61, in <module> from pygments.styles import get_all_styles ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygments'`.

Comment: Then probably it's better for you to stick with pythontex2 and not put your documents into directories with non-ASCII names :-)

Comment: This error means that pygments aren't set up for Python 3, I guess.

Comment: OK, I changed the path. Thank you for helping me : - )

Comment: You shouldn't need python3. How did you typeset the document and what editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using TeXPad on MacOS. I update my question and precise the editor/typesetting method.